# validate Datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a *datagridview* which have predefined columns. I want to validate the columns.certain columns needed to be validated in different format. My column names are unit_id,batch_id,exp_month,exp_year,tax_rate. The validations needed are all columns should not be null,exp_month and exp_date length should be 2 and 4 respectively and they must be not before the current date. The tax rate should be also in 2 digit.
And moreover the last row which automatically added should not be considered for null values.

---

[image: image of my *datagridview*]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have well understood, but If you want to apply format or check format in a cell, you can use `CellFormatting` event and do what you want inside.

Typically you could implement something like :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 || e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3 )
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex];              
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((cell.Value).ToString())) MessageBox.Show("What you want");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried _cellvalidating_ event and its not working correctly.if someone could help me it will be great.

Comment: What do you want to do if `batch_id` is null for exemple? If you don't want the row to be added, check before adding it. If you want a replacement value, `cellformatting` is the appropriate method?

Comment: the first four rows are mandatory and if it is null then it should be shown in error message or message box.please i am a new guy here so please give me the correct code if possible.

Comment: I can't give you the exact code, I can give you just a track. I don't know anything about this datagridview (binded datasource or rows programmatically added). But again I suggest you to think in another way to achieve this.